# Mutants or not?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory

Two 4-tangles (drawn unneccesarily complicated to show how they are
related - both are 6-tangles capped off with the same cap):

[image]

(alternate version with ends at the same point)
[image]

If I could turn over the inner red box...but I can't, 6-tangles have no mutants.  Nevertheless, an example where the box is asymmetric with respect to turnover:

[image]

Yet (if I didn't botch the isotopies), the two tangles in image 1 are mutants.

Can you either

- prove (maybe by induction) that both tangles are always mutants or
- give a counterexample? If it makes the 4-tangles non-algebraic, it "doesn't count" for my purpose (devising a new language for algebraic knots), but it is still good to know.

Comment: Just to clarify: Is the thing inside the box labeled 6 supposed to be a tangle with 6 ends? Is there a reason that the red box in your figure includes the extra half-twist?

Comment: On the principle that "if it doesn't look like a mutation, it probably isn't", I would say that it should be easy to show that this operation isn't  a mutation. For instance, take a sufficiently complicated example, and look at its closure (or maybe union with another complicated tangle). If the result of this operation changes an invariant known to not change under mutation, you're done. Examples include signature, Alexander/Conway/Jones polynomials, hyperbolic volume...

Comment: Your two tangles don’t have their endpoints at the same places on the boundary two-sphere. So I don’t see how to compare them…

Comment: @SamNead: That's only because I drew them for comparison that way. I added an alternate version.

Comment: @DannyRuberman: Yes, that's a 6-tangle, and the crossing is just there because if it were on the lower two strings, this whole "operation" I defined would be either illegal or pointless, and you would have to use the top-bottom mirrored operation of this. And if the "next" crossings would be on left/right top and bottom, nightmare ensues. So I added it "to be safe". It's complicated...

Comment: @DannyRuberman ad2: Good hint. The thing that confuses me is that with relative simple 6-tangles I always get mutants. There must be a reason for that.